# How to make transparent background from halo material

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

i spending many hour following this tutorial,when i finished it and try to change the background to transparent the result is not what i want.So how i achieve this for vfx on my movie.[image]

This is the link for the tutorial :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNLOjw5HYc&t=911s

Answer (score 0):

2 things here:

- To render an image with transparent background you need to check the Properties>Render>Film>Transparent checkbox

[image]

- You can easily use this asset in video production even if the background is not transparent (It's actually better if it's not transparent). In your video editor, just change the blend mode of your shockwave to "screen": this will get rid of the black parts of the image and show only the shockwave over your footage